# Redirect content of a folder to another with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to restructure some folders on my website, specifically I am want to move what's contained inside "images/" to "images/gallery/", but I don't want to break previous links, so I thought of using htaccess.

I looked up several tutorials and even several questions here on stackoverflow, tried several times, but I can't get the rewrite rule to work.

This is what I have:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) /images/gallery/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But when I try to access anything inside /images/ (for example images/test.jpg) it stays into images/test.jpg and doesn't go to images/gallery/test.jpg. So it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Any clue on what I might possibly doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Clear your browser cache ,

Comment: Hello, tried that, and also tried with several browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule at present will cause a redirect loop since `/images/` is present in both source and target URLs and you're not even using anchor `$`:

You can tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ /images/gallery/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Now pattern will match `/images/test.jpg` but won't match redirected URL `/images/gallery/test.jpg` due to use of `[^/]+` in pattern.

Make sure this rule is first after `RewriteEngine On` and there is no .htaccess in `/images/` folder.

---

**EDIT:** If your original path has sub-directories also then use:

```
RewriteRule ^images/((?!gallery/).+)$ /images/gallery/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: May I ask you an extra question? I have several folders structured this way: images/1-100/, images/101-200/, all the way to images/3701-3800/. What they have in common is that they always have a "-", the part before "-" always ends with a 1, and the full name of the folder always ends with a 0. These are the only folders I want to move, leaving alone the other folders inside /images/. Can I redirect them to images/gallery/1-100, images/gallery/101-200, etc. in one single magic rule or do I have do it individually for each folder? Thank you very much again for your wisdom!

Comment: Hey man, thanks very much for trying to help me this far. Unfortunately this one didn't work. It remains images/2001-2100/ (for example). It's weird because, reading your expression it seems to be correct, although I am a beginner when it comes to regular expressions.

Comment: It is super late for me so last comment for day. Exact same rule worked for me and redirected `http://localhost/images/2001-2100/` to `http://localhost/images/gallery/2001-2100`

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is, apparently it does redirect the directory itself, but not the files inside them. Don't worry, feel free to check it tomorrow. Thanks again, good night.

Comment: If that is a directory then use: `RewriteRule ^images/(\d*?1-\d*?0/.*)$ /images/gallery/$1 [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: Behold the regex god anubhava. Thank you so much, may I donate something to you for your help?

Comment: Glad it worked. No donation, answering problems on SO is my way of contributing something back to the community for all the open-source software I've been using for years.